# Python : map character position to word position python

Tags: python, pandas, nlp

Is there a way to automatically map the character start-end positions to the respective word positions in a text?

For example :

```python
{'text': 'Metiamide an histamine H2-receptors antagonist has been used to treat a case of Zollinger-Ellison syndrome characterized by a long standing diarrhea, an important gastric hypersecretion and a moderatly elevated plasma gastrin but without digestive ulceration.',
 'char_position': '[80.0, 106.0]'}
```

Here, the `char_position` refers to **Zollinger-Ellison syndrome**

**Wanted output** :

```python
    {'text': 'Metiamide an histamine H2-receptors antagonist has been used to treat a case of Zollinger-Ellison syndrome characterized by a long standing diarrhea, an important gastric hypersecretion and a moderatly elevated plasma gastrin but without digestive ulceration.',
     'word_position': '[13, 14]'}
```

Comment: How do you exactly define *word*?

Comment: Also, what exactly is your input? You show a dictionary but have a pandas tag

Comment: `len(text[:text.find(word)].split())` or `text.count(" ", 0, text.find(word))` will return you amount of words before `word` which is *start index*. Add to this number `len(word.split()) - 1` or `word.count(" ")` and you will get *end index*. *P.S. Options with `.count()` is more efficient.*

Comment: @OlvinRoght how do you define `word`?

Comment: @mozway my input is a dataframe, with 2 columns (text, char_position). The dictionary I provided is just a sample of the dataframe

Comment: @Daweo words are the tokens in the text

Comment: @joasa, I've just defined both `text` and `word` as string constants: `word = "Zollinger-Ellison syndrome"` and `text = "Metiamide an histamine H2-receptors antagonist has been used to treat a case of Zollinger-Ellison syndrome characterized by a long standing diarrhea, an important gastric hypersecretion and a moderatly elevated plasma gastrin but without digestive ulceration."`

Comment: Is `H2-receptors` one word or two words?

Comment: @Stef It's one word